# Elasticsearch: evacuate all data before shutdown of a data node?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to tell a node to remove all of its data (spread it back out among the other nodes) so that I can shut it down and not deal with a rebalance/re-replicate once its down?

If I have 2 copies of each shard, and I drop one node, some of the shards now only have 1 live copy and it has to be re-replicated. I'd prefer to not drop down to 1 live copy for any period of time if I can.

Answer (score 16):

After posting to the ES mailing list, I was informed the proper answer lies in the _cluster/settings api, specifically the cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip option.

From the docs: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{
  "transient" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "10.0.0.1"
  }
}'
```

The IP address can be a comma separated list. To 'un-exclude', just remove the IP from the list (or set the list to "" to remove all excluded IPs).

Hopefully this helps others looking for the answer to this same question.

Comment: Can nodes be excluded by other features, e.g. by hostname? I have all nodes having same ip address 127.0.1.1 :) which is wrong of course and should be corrected but I'd like to decomission a node somehow.

Comment: Yes, per the link above: A special attribute name called _ip can be used to match on node ip values. In addition _host attribute can be used to match on either the node’s hostname or its ip address. Similarly _name and _id attributes can be used to match on node name and node id accordingly.

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/_settings -d '{
      "index.routing.allocation.exclude._name" : "hero,other hero"
}'

Comment: Does this exclusion remove all copies of a shard - say i exclude 3 IPs which have primary and replicas for a shard. What I noticed is only 1 copy from these 3 nodes is relocated so there is a point of time when we just have one copy once the excluded IP nodes are shutdown. Could you please point me to the forum post/thread where this was discussed?

Comment: @dejavu013 Make sure all non-excluded nodes are eligible to hold the primary or secondary shards. If you have 4 servers and exclude 3 of them, then you wont have any secondaries because the secondary of a certain shard wont be on the same host as the primary (for the same shard number)