# How to remove nodes from a ES cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

Wowee...how does one remve nodes from ES?

I had 4 nodes, wanted to remove three.

On the node I wanted to keep I ran the below:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{"transient" : {"cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "172.31.6.204"}}';echo

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{"transient" : {"cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "172.31.6.205"}}';echo

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{"transient" : {"cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" : "172.31.6.206"}}';echo
```

Now my cluster health looks like this:

```
curl localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "red",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 2,
  "active_shards" : 2,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 8
```

How do I fix?  What is the proper method for removing nodes?

Thank god this was in dev...

Thanks

Comment: [Have a look at the following link it might help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055703/elasticsearch-evacuate-all-data-before-shutdown-of-a-data-node)

Answer (score 1):

Your **decommission** was **good** with `cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip` !
The problem you got is that you don't give time for shards to move, each time, to the remained nodes.

You can replay the same commands, one by one, but with paying attention to the migrating shards with some monitoring plug-ins as [ElasticHQ](http://www.elastichq.org/) or [Kopf](https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf)